# Exclude path from PHPDoc in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I am working on a wordpress site and one of the plugins (buddypress) has declarations the same as the main wordpress core functions but without the PHPDoc comments.  This means I am not getting the PHPDoc info unless I go to declaration and select which declaration I am want to look at.

Is there anyway to remove this plugins folder from the scope of PHPDoc so I can still get the info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open project window. Select your folder. Invoke context menu and select
`Mark directory as -> Excluded`

Some useful links:

1. https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/excluding-files-from-project.html
2. https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/directories.html